# Dropdowndown list options changes if a button is clicked ( VueJS & Laravel 6)

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, laravel, vue.js

I want to make my dropdown list options changes when I click a button in my form.

I have a form with 3 buttons (Accounting, Department & Cashier)

[image]

I want my Transaction dropdown list to change options depending on what department has been chosen.

[image]

I already have this JSON array for each department:

[image]

What I want is when I click a button, the option will change too in my transaction dropdown.
For example, if I click registrar, only the registrar options will be available on the dropdown.

For now, this is my vue script for pulling the arrays for options:

```
 <script>
    const app = new Vue({
        el:'#transactions',
        data:{
            trans:{}

        },
        mounted(){
            this.getTrans();
        },
        methods:{
            getTrans(){
                axios.get('http://localhost/dqrs/api/transactions')
                .then((response)=>{
                    this.trans=response.data
                    console.log(this.trans.acc);
                })

                .catch(function (error){
                    console.log(error);
                });
            }

        }
    })
</script>
```

And I just want to ask too if this is right for pulling my values for transaction:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The whole code should be like this:

1. Don't need to call getTrans() function on mounted.
2. Make template.
3. Define button click function

   ```js
   <script>
       const app = new Vue({
           el:'#transactions',
           data:{
               trans:{},
               options: []
           },
           mounted(){
               axios.get('http://localhost/dqrs/api/transactions')
                   .then((response)=>{
                       this.trans=response.data;
                       this.options = this.trans.cas;
                   })
                   .catch(function (error){
                       console.log(error);
                   });
           },
           methods:{
               btnClick: function(category) {
                   if (category == 'cash') {
                       this.options = this.trans.cas;
                   } else if (category == 'account') {
                       this.options = this.trans.acc;
                   } else {
                       this.options = this.trans.reg;
                   }
           }
       })
   </script>
   ```

   ```html
   <template>
       <div>
           <div class="d-flex">
               <button v-on:click="btnClick('cash')"></button>
               <button v-on:click="btnClick('account')"></button>
               <button v-on:click="btnClick('register')"></button>   
           </div>
           <select v-for="option in options" :key="option.id">
               <option disabled selected>Choose Transaction...</option>
               <option value="option.val">{{option.name}}</option>
           </select>
        </div>
   </template>
   ```

Answer (score 0):

You must set your `<select v-model/>` to the value you want to select!

Comment: I think the questioneer is not looking for mapping the selected data
The questioneer wants to change the options list in the dropdown depending on the button clicks
Hope this will help you answer the question better way. Thanks for your input always.

Comment: Still, 
That is only achievable by setting v-model and on click the option or Button let's say we call a function 
`:click="triggerChange("That Specific Option Value")"`

and in Function Just set the v-model . . . . !
`function triggerChange(value){
this.vModel = value ;  
}`